# Can I ground my new exhaust fan to the metal box where there is no grounded conductor?

Tags: electrical, grounding, exhaust-fan

Can I add a green ground screen to my exhaust fan's housing (metal) and connect the green ground wire to it?  There is no ground wire in the old supply wiring.

Comment: Can you post a photo of how the existing exhaust fan is hooked up, showing where the wires come into the box?

Comment: Is the old wiring in conduit or some sort of metal sheathing? If so, these may also be grounding paths.

Comment: FYI "*grounded*" conductor means the neutral, whereas "*grounding*" conductor is the equipment ground. What exactly are you referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but it won't do anything. The term "ground" implies an electrical connection to the Earth, which is normally provided by the bare grounded conductor.

Answer (score 0):

If the "old supply wiring" has no ground, and ground is not available by conduit or nearby plumbing, then you would have to install a new cable that contains a ground wire. Unfortunately, the NEC does not permit using the neutral (aka grounded conductor) as the equipment ground per 250.136(B)